# set member variable throws error 'argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable'

Tags: python

I am using a set class variable to represent page links that have been crawled in a web crawler. I try to run my program and it tells me that the set is a Nonetype and that it can't be iterated through

```
class Creeper:

    project_name = ''
    base_url = ''
    domain_name = ''
    queue_file = ''
    crawled_file = ''
    queue = set()
    crawled = set()

    def __init__(self, base_url, project_name, domain_name):
        Creeper.project_name = project_name
        Creeper.base_url = base_url
        Creeper.domain_name = domain_name
        Creeper.queue_file = Creeper.project_name + '/queue.txt'
        Creeper.crawled_file = Creeper.project_name + '/crawled.txt'
        self.boot()
        self.crawl_page('First creeper', Creeper.base_url)

    @staticmethod
    def crawl_page(thread_name, page_url):
        if page_url not in Creeper.crawled:
            print(thread_name + ' now crawling ' + page_url)
            print('Queue: ' + str(len(Creeper.queue)) + ' | Crawled: ' + str(len(Creeper.crawled)))
            Creeper.queue_links(Creeper.gather_links(page_url))
            Creeper.queue.remove(page_url)
            Creeper.crawled.add(page_url)
            Creeper.update_files()
```

the if statement in crawl_page is the location of the problem, the passed page_url should not be originally in the set and it should enter the body, however, I get a Nonetype error

This is the current error message I am receiving

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/courtmiddleton/Desktop/PycharmProjects/creepyCrawler/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    Creeper(HOMEPAGE, PROJECT_NAME, DOMAIN_NAME)
  File "/Users/courtmiddleton/Desktop/PycharmProjects/creepyCrawler/creeper.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.crawl_page('First creeper', Creeper.base_url)
  File "/Users/courtmiddleton/Desktop/PycharmProjects/creepyCrawler/creeper.py", line 34, in crawl_page
    if page_url not in Creeper.crawled:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: Code formatting is started and ended with a line containing only three *backticks*, not three single-quotes.

Comment: BTW, generally, `Creeper.project_name = ...` is very much the wrong thing; use `self.project_name = ...` to modify only the current instance, not the class itself (and generally, you should use `self.` everywhere else, remove the `@staticmethod` decorator, and accept a `self` argument in `crawl_page`; otherwise, there's little/no point to using a class *at all*).

Comment: ...when you use `MyClass.foo`, you aren't referring to a *member* variable at all, you're referring to a *class* variable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `@staticmethod` and replace all the `Creeper.x` by `self.x`. Also, you need `self` in the method definition as follows. I have not tested your code, but this should at least be okay at a design level.

Because you had `Creeper.x` the class attributes and its methods could not access one another and the `.crawled` attribute remained an empty set since the instantiation of `Creeper` class. @CharlesDuffy also had pointed this out in his comments.

```py
class Creeper:

    project_name = ''
    base_url = ''
    domain_name = ''
    queue_file = ''
    crawled_file = ''
    queue = set()
    crawled = set()

    def __init__(self, base_url, project_name, domain_name):
        self.project_name = project_name
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.domain_name = domain_name
        self.queue_file = self.project_name + '/queue.txt'
        self.crawled_file = self.project_name + '/crawled.txt'
        self.boot()
        self.crawl_page('First creeper', self.base_url)

    #@staticmethod
    def crawl_page(self, thread_name, page_url):
        if page_url not in self.crawled:
            print(thread_name + ' now crawling ' + page_url)
            print('Queue: ' + str(len(self.queue)) + ' | Crawled: ' + str(len(self.crawled)))
            self.queue_links(self.gather_links(page_url))
            self.queue.remove(page_url)
            self.crawled.add(page_url)
            self.update_files()
```

I would suggest you take a look at [**Python `class` documentation**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) for more clarity.